# Have settings in a python module

Tags: python

I wrote a python module for some global functions I often use in my other scripts. 
As it connects to an API I would need to tell it login credentials and a hostname to connect to. 
Currently I made it like this in my module:

```
# set URL and API version
URL = ""
API = ""

# set login
USER = ""
PASS = ""
```

And then I use it in my other scripts like this:

```
import MyModule as t
# set URL
t.URL = "someapi.server.com"
t.API = "v3"
t.USER = raw_input("Username:")
t.PASS = getpass.getpass("Password for " + t.USER + ":")
```

But I want to make my module be available to others as well and therefore I like to validate the URL and API version before I allow use of the other functions in the module. Maybe I am totally wrong with this and the way I have it now is just right? 
I tried in my module to validate the values, but at the moment it get's imported the variables are not set and are for sure fail by my check. 
Is there any best practice on such?

Comment: Maybe you can use a class to hold the configuration instead of global variables. Then you can validate the values in the constructor: `import MyModule as t`, `t.conf = t.Configuration(url, api, user, pass)`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting such information in global variables seems inappropriate because of leakage between places where you want different values, possibility of use before initialization, etc.

I suggest a more explicit representation of your configuration, for example passing around an ad-hoc class defined in your module:

```
class xxx_api_conf:
    def __init__(self,version,url,user,password):
        self.version=version
        self.url=url
        self.user=user
        self.password=password
```

Comment: How exactly would I use it then in another script? 'import MyModule as t' , t.xxx_api_conf('v3', 'api.server.com', 'Admin', 'Secret') ?

Comment: yes, initialize the configuration object as appropriate for the client and pass it to all functions that need the configuration.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I still have a question. I could use the class gobally, set it just once, like I do it now with my global variables or would it be better if I would just use the class to create a settings object and pass this object always with every function call I use? e.g. `MyModule.conf = MyModule.xxx_api_conf(this, that)` vs. `conn = MyModule.xxx_api_conf(this that)` + in every function call `MyModule.query(conn, myquery)`